# VBA 2010 - CDate Type Mismatch Issue

Tags: excel, date, format, vba

I have the following code that runs without issue on some laptops and then others it will error out with a Type Mismatch. In Column AA are Dates with format (mm/dd/yyyy) and Column AB has the respective Times with format (hh:mm:ss).
I am subtracting the date and time from Now(). I am unable to really troubleshoot the issue because it works fine on my laptop. For others, it errors out. `CLng(CDate(Now()))` has a value but the other two induce type mismatch. I've tried the two lines below and also another which concatenated the date and time, then performed CLng(CDate(.

```
'If CLng(CDate(Now())) - CLng(CDate(Range("AA" & i).Value)) + CLng(CDate(Range("AB" & i).Value)) >= 7 Then
 If CLng(CDate(Now())) - CLng(CDate(FMT(Range("AA" & i), "mm/dd/yyyy"))) + CLng(CDate(FMT(Range("AB" & i), "hh:mm:ss"))) >= 7 Then
```

where FMT is a public function:

```
Public Function FMT$(ByVal Value, ByVal strFormat)
FMT = VBA.Format$(Value, strFormat)
End Function
```

I am requesting my colleague to send me a screenshot of his region date/time settings.. I was thinking this could be the case. I've read other questions similar to this but not able to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The time portion of a `Date` is a fraction.  Using `CLng` on a `Date` that only contains a time will round away from noon. What exactly are you trying to calculate?

Comment: In Column AA are Dates with format (mm/dd/yyyy) and Column AB has the respective Times with format (hh:mm:ss). I would like to subtract the date and time from Now(). Thanks for the info on CLng. Initially, I concatenated the date and time and then used CLng, which worked great for me. But for others, it didn't work so I thought there may have been something wrong with how I concatenated so I split up the date and time. But that wasn't the case.

Comment: Do you have dates and times in columns AA and AB, or do you have strings that look like dates and times in those columns?  (If you switch the cell format to `General` temporarily and the cells show numbers, then the contents were dates/times, but if they continue to show things that look like dates and times, then the contents are just strings.)

Comment: I did a Format check on it and it is Text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If columns AA and AB contain text rather than dates and times, try using the following statement:

```
If Now() - (DateValue(Range("AA" & i)) + TimeValue(Range("AB" & i))) >= 7 Then
```

This will probably still be problematic if the users have a local date setting of, for instance, `dd/mm/yyyy` but your columns are storing a string representing a date in some other locale's date setting.  If that is the case, you may need to parse the fields and do it as follows:

```
Dim myDateStr As String
Dim myTimeStr As String
Dim myDateTime As Date
myDateStr = Range("AA" & i)
myTimeStr = Range("AB" & i)
myDateTime = DateSerial(CInt(Mid(myDateStr, 7, 4)), CInt(Mid(myDateStr, 1, 2)), CInt(Mid(myDateStr, 4, 2))) + _
             TimeSerial(CInt(Mid(myTimeStr, 1, 2)), CInt(Mid(myTimeStr, 4, 2)), CInt(Mid(myTimeStr, 7, 2)))

If Now() - myDateTime >= 7 Then
```

Comment: That worked for me! I am going to make sure it works for the others real quick, but I think this may do the trick. I will followup asap.

Comment: I see.. I was hoping there would be a solution to avoid having to customize the code for each individual based on their settings..  It would be a lot of work to update this for each person each time there is a revision. Is there an option to change the format from text to a usable format to bypass this?

Comment: @jmeddy - If the values in AA and AB are stored in the user's date/time settings, the first method I supplied would work.  If the values in AA and AB are stored in a fixed mm/dd/yyyy and hh:mm:ss setting then the alternate code I supplied will work, irrespective of the user's settings.

Comment: It is working like a charm with the alternate code you provided. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Value2` property of the `Range` object to get the numerical representation of a `DateTime`. Try:

```
If CDbl(Now()) - (Range("AA" & i).Value2 + Range("AB" & i).Value2) >= 7 Then
```

Just be sure to convert `Now()` to `Double`, otherwise it will use just the date part of the `DateTime`.

I find it easier to work with the numerical representation of the `DateTime`, as it allows you to bypass the regional settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it and am getting a Type Mismatch for the same section: `(Range("AA" & i).Value2 + Range("AB" & i).Value2)`.. When I hover the mouse over `Range("AA" & i).Value2` I get MM/DD/YYYY and for `Range("AB" & i).Value2` I get hh:mm:ss.   CDbl(Now()) gives the numerical representation of 42703.48.. Seems like I still need to find a way to convert to numerical representation without using regional settings?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but i think your answer would've worked if my date/time format in columns AA/AB weren't text..?